# Decode text prior to $("#textbox").val() call?

Tags: jquery, textbox, decode, encode

My web page makes AJAX calls to a server and displays the result in the browser. The contents of the result will frequently contain a portion of the text string that the user submitted in the AJAX request. So if the user types `<script>` in his query, the returned output will likely contain the phrase `<script>` too. The server encodes the response before sending it, however, so the returned phrase actually would be received as `&lt;script&gt;`

This is all well and good. The scripting vulnerability is removed and the browser properly displays `<script>` when showing the response.

The problem is when I want to take the return value and stuff it into a text box. Consider:

```
$(“#someTextBox”).val(“&lt;script&gt;”);
```

The contents of the text box are displayed in encoded form (i.e. `&lt;script&gt;`) instead of in decoded form (i.e. `<script>`).

Questions:

[1] How do I decode the value prior to the call to val()?

[2] Am I introducing a security vulnerability by doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite possibly a more straightforward method for doing this, but seems to get the desired result.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZPLTc/

More info here ( where I got concept ) http://debuggable.com/posts/encode-html-entities-with-jquery:480f4dd6-13cc-4ce9-8071-4710cbdd56cb

Comment: Thank you. Your solution can be applied using the following code: `return $("<div/>").html(encodedText).text();` Other posts on this site indicate that this technique should only be used with trusted data. In my case, I trust the AJAX server because it properly encodes its responses. But an untrusted server returning an unencoded `<script>` block would trigger execution of that script -- despite the fact that the temporal `<div>` isn't even connected to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the HTML entities into '<' and '>' using 'replace': https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace. This doesn't introduce a vulnerability as long as you only use the string in your textbox. If you put it into a div or anything other than an input box,  tags will be exposed.

Comment: makes sense -- although then I'd have to replace not only the angle brackets, but also every other escapable character (e.g. quotes, etc.)